# V2 Azure Function dependency injection and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Binder

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have successfully used the dependency injection for my own custom services as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).

What I would like is to use the Binder that the framework injects as a parameter into Azure Functions in my custom service.
Example of use as a function parameter:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
```

I tried just adding the Binder as an argument to my services constructor and letting the framework create the instance of my service but the Binder passed in is always null.

My service constructor:

```
public MyService(Binder binder)
```

Registered like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();
```

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: shavua tov, have you attempted my example?

Answer (score 0):

You would first have to create a class like this that allows you to read/write:

```
   public static class Bindor
    {
        public static async Task<string> ReadFromBlob(string path, Binder binder, string connection)
        {
            var attributes = new Attribute[]
            {
                    new BlobAttribute(path),
                    new StorageAccountAttribute(connection)
            };

            using (var reader = await binder.BindAsync<TextReader>(attributes))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }

        public static async Task BindToBlob(string path, Binder binder, object payload, string connection)
        {
            var attributes = new Attribute[]
            {
                    new BlobAttribute(path),
                    new StorageAccountAttribute(connection)
            };
            using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes))
            {
                writer.Write(payload);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you would include `Binder binder` as a parameter in your function (just like you are doing).

Example usage would be something like:

```
//path would be your path to the blob (including the container)
//binder is the parameter from your function signature
//sorry about the confusing naming, Bindor is the class we created, whereas Binder is the functions class
await Bindor.BindToBlob(path, binder, "my payload", connection);
```

Comment: This definitely works and I will use it if its the only option.

Comment: Should I assume that because you are passing the Binder as a function parameter that using dependency injection during the creation of my service is not an option? It would be far cleaner if my service could receive the binder at creation time and just store a reference to it. I haven't looked at the framework source for this so maybe there is a valid reason that the binder is scoped to a function call.

Comment: i dont know. the way to use `Binder` is different than using the newly-added feature _dependency injenction_ for azure functions (this feature was added perhaps around 6 months ago)